# Mining pools like eligius

Tags: mining-pools, non-standard-transaction

Can someone provide a list of mining pools like eligius who will accept non standard transactions directly and mine them?

Answer (score 1):

No pool today includes non-standard transactions in blocks.

To be correct, there are a number of conditions and pool options. Some pools have strict rules, some pools - no. But all pools today have their own policy rules for accepting or rejecting transactions to a mempool.

There is no correct answer to your question without knowledge what kind of standardness do you mean. The only thing you can do is connecting to all nodes and broadcasing your transaction hoping someone will accept it.

Comment: I mean a transaction like: https://blockchain.info/tx/91c8b08f305d895d6bc8f43bbdd36dcbc7f1d998e3df5e8f13dd9cdeebf15cb5?show_adv=true

Comment: this transaction is standard today. every pool will accept it